# How to use (home) brew install python 3.6.5_1

Tags: install, homebrew, python

I am trying to install python 3.6.5_1 using Homebrew by running the following:

```
$ brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/f2a764ef944b1080be64bd88dca9a1d80130c558/Formula/python.rb
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Error: python contains a recursive dependency on itself: python depends on sphinx-doc sphinx-doc depends on python
```

How do I deal with it?

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/25093

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `--ignore-dependencies`:

```
brew install --ignore-dependencies https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/f2a764ef944b1080be64bd88dca9a1d80130c558/Formula/python.rb
```